# Converting polynomial interpolations to Bézier splines

Tags: quadratics, interpolation, cubics, bezier-curve

### The search

I needed to convert some quadratic interpolation plots (from PiCTeX) to 
quadratic Bézier splines (for SVG). I saw this question asked several times 
elsewhere but never with the kind of answer I was looking for. I finally just 
did my own calculations, and in the process also discovered how to do handle 
the cubic case.

### The quadratic case

The interplolation plots are splines (piecewise 
interpolations), each segment of which is specified by three points: two 
endpoints and a midpoint. The endpoints of adjoining segments coincide.
PiCTeX computes and plots a quadratic curve through these three points using 
Lagrangian interpolation.

Quadratic Bézier splines are also in segments specified by three points:  two 
endpoints and a middle control point.

The difference between these two is in the middle point.  In the interpolation 
spline, the midpoint is on the curve, but in the Bézier spline, the middle 
point is off the curve (unless the "curve" is a straight line).

Call the endpoints $a$ and $b$, the interpolation midpoint $m$, and the Bézier 
middle control point $q$.  Using the parameterization $0 \le T \le 1$, the 
Lagrangian quadratic interpolation $P(T)$ through points $a$, $m$, $b$ has 
$P(0) = a$, $P(\frac12) = m$, $P(1) = b$, and

$$\eqalign{
  P(T) &= \frac{(T-\frac12)(T-1)}{(-\frac12)(-1)} a
          + \frac{T(T-1)}{(\frac12)(-\frac12)} m + \frac{T(T-\frac12)}{1(\frac12)} b \cr
       &= (2T^2 - 3T + 1) a - 4(T^2 - T) m + (2T^2 - T) b
}$$

The corresponding quadratic Bézier curve, where $q$ is the middle control 
point, is

$$\eqalign{
  B(T) &= (1-T)^2 a + 2(1-T)T q + T^2 b \cr
       &= (1-2T+T^2) a + 2(T-T^2) q + T^2 b
}$$

At $T = \frac12$, these are

$$\eqalign{
  P({\textstyle\frac12}) &= m \cr
  B({\textstyle\frac12}) &= \frac14 a + \frac12 q + \frac14 b
}$$

If $P(\frac12) = B(\frac12)$ then

$$
  m = \frac14 a + \frac12 q + \frac14 b
$$

**Key result:** Solving the previous equation for $q$ gives

$$
  q = - \frac12 a + 2 m - \frac12 b
$$

**Possibly unnecessary verification:**  The above shows that these two 
curves have three points in common.  Since they are both quadratic functions 
of $T$, it may be unnessary to further verify that the two curves coincide. But 
I did this anyway by substituting this value for $q$ into $B(T)$ and 
finding it always equals $P(T)$:

$$\eqalign{
  B(T) &= (1-2T-T^2) a + 2(T-T^2) \left(-\frac12 a + 2 m - \frac12 b \right) + T^2 b \cr
       &= (2T^2-3T+1) a - 4(T^2-T) m + (2T^2-T) b \cr
       &= P(T)
}$$

### The cubic case

Cubic interpolation plots have two midpoints $m$ and $n$, and cubic Bézier 
plots have two middle control points $p$ and $q$.  Using conventions analogous 
to those above, we have

$$\eqalign{
  P(T) = &\ \frac{(T-\frac13)(T-\frac23)(T-1)      }{(-\frac13)(-\frac23)(-1      )} a
          + \frac{ T         (T-\frac23)(T-1)      }{( \frac13)(-\frac13)(-\frac23)} m \cr
         &+ \frac{ T         (T-\frac13)(T-1)      }{( \frac23)( \frac13)(-\frac13)} n
          + \frac{ T         (T-\frac13)(T-\frac23)}{        1 ( \frac23)( \frac13)} b \cr
       = &- \frac92    \left( T^3 - 2       T^2 + \frac{11}9 T - \frac29 \right) a 
          + \frac{27}2 \left( T^3 - \frac53 T^2 + \frac23    T           \right) m \cr
         &- \frac{27}2 \left( T^3 - \frac43 T^2 + \frac13    T           \right) n 
          + \frac92    \left( T^3 -         T^2 + \frac29    T           \right) b \cr
  B(T) =&\ (1-T)^3 a + 3(1-T)^2T p + 3(1-T)T^2 q + T^3 b \cr
       =&\ (-T^3+3T^2-3T+1) a + 3(T^3-2T^2+T) p + 3(-T^3+T^2) q + T^3 b
}$$

At $T = \frac13$ and $\frac23$, these are

$$\eqalign{
  P({\textstyle\frac13}) &= m \cr
  B({\textstyle\frac13}) &= \frac8{27} a + \frac49 p + \frac29 q + \frac1{27} b \cr
  P({\textstyle\frac23}) &= n \cr
  B({\textstyle\frac23}) &= \frac1{27} a + \frac29 p + \frac49 q + \frac8{27} b
}$$

If $P(\frac13) = B(\frac13)$ and $P(\frac23) = B(\frac23)$ then

$$\eqalign{
  m &= \frac8{27} a + \frac49 p + \frac29 q + \frac1{27} b \cr
  n &= \frac1{27} a + \frac29 p + \frac49 q + \frac8{27} b
}$$

Then

$$\eqalign{
  -2m +  n &= - \frac{15}{27} a - \frac69 p + \frac{ 6}{27} b \cr
    m - 2n &=   \frac{ 6}{27} a - \frac69 q - \frac{15}{27} b
}$$

**Key result:** Solving the previous system for $p$ and $q$ gives

$$\eqalign{
  p &= - \frac56 a + 3       m - \frac32 n + \frac13 b \cr
  q &=   \frac13 a - \frac32 m + 3       n - \frac56 b
}$$

**Possibly unnecessary verification:**  The above shows that the two cubic 
curves have four points in common, which may be enough to show that they 
coincide, but subsituting the values for $p$ and $q$ into $B(T)$ explicitly 
shows that it always equals $P(T)$:

$$\eqalign{
  B(T) = &\ (-T^3+3T^2-3T+1) a \cr
         &+ 3 (T^3-2T^2+T) \left( -\frac56a + 3m - \frac32n + \frac13b \right) \cr
         &+ 3 (-T^3+T^2) \left( \frac13a - \frac32m + 3n - \frac56b \right)  \cr
         &+ T^3 b \cr
       = &\  \left( -\frac92 T^3 + 9 T^2 - \frac{11}2 T + 1 \right)  a \cr
         &+  \left( \frac{27}2 T^3 + \frac{45}2 T^2 + 9 T \right)  m \cr
         &+  \left( -\frac{27}2 T^3 + \frac{36}2 T^2 - \frac92 T \right)  n \cr
         &+  \left( \frac92 T^3 - \frac92 T^2 + T \right)  b \cr
       = &P(T)
}$$

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Basically, what you have described is the change of basis between the Lagrange and Bernstein bases.

Comment: bubba, thanks for the information on Lagrange and Bernstein bases.  But no, I did not have a question.  I'm simply posting information which I think others might find useful.  Stack Overflow explicitly encourages users to make such postings, and I presumed this is ok elsewhere in Stack Exchange.  Correct me if I'm wrong - https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question. In fact, as far as I can see, there isn't a question. But, anyway ...

The equation
$$
m = \frac14 a + \frac12 q + \frac14 b
$$
can be written as
$$
m = \frac12 q + \frac12\left( \frac12 a + \frac12 b \right)
  = \frac12 q + \frac12 c
$$
where $c = \tfrac12(a+b)$ is the mid-point of the triangle side $ab$. So, $m$ is the mid-point of a median of the triangle $aqb$. Along the same lines, we have
$$
q = 2m - c = c+ 2(m-c)
$$
which has a similar geometric interpretation.

You can do the same sorts of things with cubics, but the geometric pictures are not quite as nice.

The cubic case is covered in detail in [this book by Mortenson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0831132981).

Comment: Thanks for these additional details.  The geometric interpretations are interesting.